# Function type with property in Kotlin

Tags: javascript, typescript, kotlin

I can specify this in TypeScript (thus can be done in JavaScript):

```
interface Foo {
  (arg: any): void
  foo: string
}
```

Can the same thing achieved in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be expressed in Kotlin, too:

```
interface Foo {
  fun funX(arg: Any): Unit
  val foo: String
}
```

[Properties in Interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html#properties-in-interfaces)

Comment: Changing `funX` to `operator fun invoke` also works, forcing implementors to act like a function. It seems closer to the TypeScript.